# Linq To Sql - оптимизация работы

Tags: sql-server, linq2sql, c#

Для доступа к базе нужен экземпляр `DataContext`.
Но как эффективно его использовать?

Сделать его глобальным для всего проекта? Тогда для одновременных запросов будут выдаваться ошибки типа:

> "Specified cast is not valid."

или

> "InvalidCastException"

или

> "DataReader is closed".

Сделать единственный экземпляр для одной страницы? Тогда тоже могут получаться такие же эксепшены, если со страницы выполнить много запросов.

Делать каждый новый экземпляр для любого запроса? Тогда это уж совсем долго (как я понимаю: создание объекта + коннект к базе). Но ошибки тогда не появляются.

Что делать? Подскажите! Может есть другие решения? Хочется чтобы можно было много запросов одновременных отправлять и по скорости было как можно быстрее:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать отдельный `DataContext` для каждого потока. Самый простой способ - объявить его статическим с атрибутом `ThreadLocal`. Правда, тут есть один недостаток - непонятно, как его потом освобождать. Решение зависит от того, как реализовано параллельное выполнение - используется пул потоков или для каждой задачи поток создается заново.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше создавать `DataContext` в месте использования, в блоке `using`. Используемый там пул подключений автоматически разрулит всё, что требуется для быстрого подключения к БД. Подключения ADO.NET не являются потокобезопасными, использовать один глобальный экземпляр подключения (который используется внутри `DataContext`) в одном многопоточном приложении нельзя. Особенно с транзакциями - в два счёта можно нарваться на deadlock.

Кроме того, Вам нужно позаботиться о том, чтобы контекст данных не пересоздавался слишком часто. Иначе говоря, чтобы Ваше приложение обращалось к БД относительно крупными блоками.

Comment: А если есть куча методов, которым нужно подключение к базе и 1 метод вызывает 2 метод, который вызывает 3 метод, кторый вызывает 4 метод, то будет создано 4 экземпляра???? Не выглядит очень эффективно.

Получается вы выбрали наихудший вариант по производительности (3) из тех, которые я предложил...

Comment: В этом случае методы должны принимать экземпляр DataContext и обращаться к нему. А уже код, который вызывает их на верхнем уровне, должен создавать экземпляр DataContext и передавать его.

Кроме того. Вы профайлером смотрели, сколько создаётся DataContext? Вы уверены, что это будет узким местом, даже если его каждый раз пересоздавать?

Comment: Не уверен, поэтому и спросил:)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите ответы на подобные вопросы:

- [LINQ to SQL - where does your DataContext live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196253/linq-to-sql-where-does-your-datacontext-live/196264#196264)
- [Multiple/single instance of Linq to SQL DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226127/multiple-single-instance-of-linq-to-sql-datacontext/226462#226462)